# What does MS SQL Server do if I UPDATE one table FROM a completely unrelated table

Tags: sql, sql-server

So say I have two tables, `TableA` and `TableB`. They are entirely unrelated. They have no common columns, no foreign key constraints, etc.

It appears I can execute

```
UPDATE TableA SET some_column = b.unrelated_column FROM TableB b;
```

and it completes without error.

But what is happening here? There is no meaningful way to match up the rows in the two tables, so what is SQL Server doing?

Answer (score 4):

From [`UPDATE`'s Best Practices](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/update-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#best-practices):

> Use caution when specifying the FROM clause to provide the criteria for the update operation. The results of an UPDATE statement are undefined if the statement includes a FROM clause that is not specified in such a way that only one value is available for each column occurrence that is updated

Well, that's certainly the case here! So what happens is that each row of Table A will have its `some_column` value set to an *arbitrary* `unrelated_column` value from Table B.

Comment: Accepting that it is in fact undefined, do you happen to know on an implementation level what SQL Server *actually* does? What strategy is used to align columns on the happy path that happens to silently produce nonsense in the case where there is no meaningful alignment?

Comment: @UtterlyConfused - it can do anything it's allowed to do, and what actually happens may vary arbitrarily between executions of the same statement. It may depend, among other things, on the specific version (including patching) of the server, the amount of memory, which other queries have executed recently or are currently being executed, probably the phase of the moon too. If you want it to do something *deterministic*, use the tools at your disposal to give it a deterministic query.

Comment: *"the phase of the moon too."* I suspect this has the biggest effect on the change in results. ;)